# Configuring xcache cacher

Tags: php, vps, xcache

I've just setup xcache on a vps server.

I have the admin section running and it is showing that xcache is running.

I am however a bit unsure about some of the settings - the [documentation](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/wiki/XcacheIni) doesn't dwell very far into what each setting mean.

*Notes that may be useful*:

- In the current setup I'm only interested in the basic opcode cacher, not the var data component.
- The server is a VPS with 2GB memory (not sure about CPU config but could find out if critical to know) and it's running a CentOS 5.x OS with cPanel/WHM.
- I have root access and the server will only host one website.

The version of php is:

```
PHP 5.4.21 (cli) (built: Nov 15 2013 10:15:53) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with XCache v3.0.3, Copyright (c) 2005-2013, by mOo
    with XCache Cacher v3.0.3, Copyright (c) 2005-2013, by mOo
```

**Question 1**

The default settings from the installation has:

```
xcache.shm_scheme = mmap
xcache.mmap_path = /dev/zero
```

*Why is mmap_path set to /dev/zero? doesn't this negate the whole thing? should it be set to a fixed file path.*

**Question 2**

The other "size" settings are:

```
cache.size = 16M
xcache.slots = 8K
xcache.count = 1
```

*Is there a methodical approach that can be used to work out the best configuration for these?*

The stats are currently as such:

[image: xcache summary]

[image: xcache summary continued]

*Note:* I have seen it maxed out 100% usage previously.

**Question 3**

*What does `xcache.optimizer` do?*

The [FAQ](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/wiki/Faq#Ihavereadthatxcache.optimizersettinggivesanimportantperformancegain.Isthattrue) says

> Currently only the "cacher" and "coverager" modules are implemented,
>   tested and known to be working, the "optimizer" does nothing. it will
>   be available only in XCache version 2, which is in an early
>   development stage.

But i somehow appear to have XCache 3.0.3 installed o_O

Comment: Why wasting your time to xcache when PHP 5.5 already have built in opcode cacher?

Comment: @OZ_ thanks for your input. I would need to confirm that several components on the server are indeed fine with php 5.5, which in itself would be time consuming too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Xcache documentation is very poorly maintained, and I recently did my best to work through what is available, answering a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431759/xcache-how-does-it-work-code-coverage-clogs-ooms/). I'll paraphrase a bit to hit your specific points.

#### xcache.mmap_path

If this is set to an empty or invalid path the cacher will turn off. I believe this should be a writeable directory. (On linux servers the default `/dev/zero/` should work; on OSX this failed so I successfully used `/tmp/xcache/` instead)

#### Opcode cacher: size, count, slots

- **xcache.count** refers to the number of cache threads and correlates to the number of CPU cores you want to utilize — the idea is that [multithreading](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/wiki/SplittedCache) should be faster if you have a multicore processor

  - valid values are 2^n like 1, 2, 4, 8
  - 0 will disable the cacher
  - non-valid values will be rounded to the nearest valid value

    - i.e. 3 will become 4
    - i.e. 5 will become 8
- **xcache.size** refers to the aggregate memory of all cache threads. So, each thread gets roughly `size/count` amount of memory
- **xcache.slots** defaults 8k unless you want to improve something specific

  - more slots (more granular) should lead to more efficient use of space (fit more data in the cache)
  - fewer slots (less granular) should lead to faster read times and more overall stability

The cacher also allows for a user controlled variable cache, with analogous settings and consequences.

#### Optimizer

This feature seems to be abandoned, or indefinitely under development — ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for your input Mark. In regards to mmap_path, doesn't `/dev/zero` negate the idea of somewhere "suitable for temp files" ?

Comment: the similar question link gives me a Page not found btw.

Comment: Ooops, question link fixed! And, I amended the 'temp files' out; you're right, it doesn't write any files… but I think it needs a "[data sink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/zero)"

Comment: Still a bit confused why `/dev/zero` would be useful but thanks for elaborating.

Comment: and thanks for fixing the link to the other answer (can't believe you didn't get points for it - I just upvoted it)

Comment: Just to complete this, but according to wikipedia "When `/dev/zero` is memory-mapped, e.g., with `mmap`, to the virtual address space, it is equivalent to using anonymous memory; i.e. memory not connected to any file."